# Should we be replacing `X` with `X.org`?

Tags: discussion

Several times now I've seen people asking questions about `X` and noticed that their posts have been edited to replace `X` with `X.org`. Is this the right way to go?

I was always taught that X should be called `X`, `X11` or `The X Window System` but never `X Windows`, and until recently I'd not seen `X.Org` used in this way. I was under the impression that `X.org` was the project and the organisation, but that people still called the software `X` etc.

I can see that `X` on it's own may assume a little too much for our potential target audience, but is `X.org` any better? Certainly if you go to [X.org](http://www.x.org/wiki/), if you didn't know what X was it would not be obvious what X is, what it is for or why you might care.

I would prefer if we use `The X Window System` and make the first reference a link to the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) which should give people plenty of references to read up on if they are interested.

Answer (score 2):

Someone early on created the [x.org](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x.org) tag. I had never seen `X` referred to this way either.

Yesterday I replaced [x.org](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x.org) with [xorg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg). I think that can also be synonymous with [x11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11).

That's plenty. Any more related to `X` would just be diluting the existing tags, and just [x](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x) would be misleading for beginners.

So if you seen `X` referred to by any other tag please change it.

**Summary**:

The two tags that can be used for `X` questions are [xorg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg) and [x11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x11). Either is fine.

Comment: I hadn't thought about tags, so thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: @MarkBooth I think the tag part is the most important.

Comment: Quite right, I just hadn't thought about it, so good catch.